# Any solution to duplication of function arguments in Python?

Tags: python, function, duplicates

I was wondering whether I can avoid using the same arguments when using a function within another one. I will give you a chunk of code to make it clear:

```
def calculateQC(self,dic_symbols:dict) -> float:

        str_quality = self.quality
        length_seq = len(str_quality)
        num_qc = 0

        for symbol in str_quality:
            num_value = dic_symbols[symbol]
            num_qc += num_value

        mean_qc = num_qc/length_seq
        return(mean_qc)    


def FastqtoFasta(self,min_qual:int,dic_symbols:dict) -> FastaFile:
        header,sequence,qualc = self.info,self.seq,self.quality
        qualc = self.calculateQC(dic_symbols)

        if qualc >= min_qual:
            print(">%s\n%s" %(header,sequence))
```

As you can see, the function FastqtoFasta includes another function called calculateQC, which requires a dictionary as an argument. As a consequence, I must also provide the FastqtoFasta with the dictionary in order to work it out or otherwise I would not be able to use calculateQC (error).

Is there a more straightforward solution to this or is this just the only way?

Thanks.

Comment: What is *wrong* with this way?  Presumably, `calculateQC` will be called from other points in the code; if not, why is it a separate function?

Comment: turn the dictionary into an instance attribute? more code should be shown for a more proper suggestion

Comment: Yes, calculateQC could be used independently. But imagine FastqtoFasta involved not only 1 function but 5 (each of them with their arguments). That implies that FastqtoFasta must also consider the arguments of all those functions, which results (in my opinion) in an ugly code.

Comment: If that is the case (you need five dicts to pass through to five functions), then that's partly just how it is: you set up your functions, and in particular your overarching FastqtoFasta function to be that flexible, requiring a lot of arguments. Alternatives might be to set the dicts beforehand (as suggested by @cards above), pass a list or dict of dicts (each element is passed to each function), or rethink your data and class structure.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest passing arguments via `**kwargs` (dictionary) if you want loose sharing of args across a stack of functions.

```
def calculateQC(self, **kwargs) -> float:
   dic_symbols = kwargs.get('symbols')
   ## do stuff

def FastqtoFasta(self, **kwargs) -> FastaFile:
    min_qual = kwargs['min']
    qualc = self.calculateQC(**kwargs)
    ## do stuff
```

To call the function:

```
 myObj.FastqtoFasta( min=#, symbols= {...})
```

Comment: This makes the function less clear, because one can't see that `min` is a (required) argument to `FastqtoFasta`. Besides, you're still passing a dict, but it's now called `kwargs`).

Comment: You are right that with kwargs you can't see the arguments in the signature of the function - it has to be in the documentation.   But you gain flexibility that the signature can be extended and pass thru the stack w/o changes. 

I think you answered your own question... "whether I can avoid using the same arguments" 

PS. with kwargs you are passing a dict of args....  not passing args.